# When creating pdf of html page with dinktopdf library, correct display does not occur

Tags: asp.net-core, view, converters, pdf-conversion, dinktopdf

I want to render the html page and create a pdf file with the dinktopdf library. The pdf file I created does not have the same view as my view page. it doesn't get the table structure, it doesn't see the text-center lines and starts the text from the left and doesn't take the png images either, they appear blank.
My class that I created pdf is as below. Here I make my settings about the dinktopdf library and convert the html page to pdf.

```
public async Task<byte[]> GeneratePDF2(string htmlContent)
        {
            var doc = new HtmlToPdfDocument()
            {
                GlobalSettings =
                {
                    ColorMode = ColorMode.Color,
                    Orientation = Orientation.Portrait,
                    PaperSize = PaperKind.A4,
                },
                Objects = 
                {
                    new ObjectSettings()
                    {
                        PagesCount = true,
                        HtmlContent = htmlContent,
                        WebSettings = { DefaultEncoding = "utf-8" },
                        FooterSettings = { FontName = "Arial", FontSize = 9, Right = "Sayfa [page] / [toPage]", Line = true }
                    }
                }
            };

            var pdf = _converter.Convert(doc);
            return pdf;
        }
```

here is the PDFController. When I say create pdf on my view page, it connects to the relevant controller and fills my model.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GeneratePDF(Guid GUID)
        {
            Certificate_Dto model = new Certificate_Dto();

            var applicationVW = await _serviceManager.VW_Applications.GetEntityAsync(x => x.GUID == GUID);
            if (applicationVW != null)
            {
                string CourseMakersJSON = _serviceManager.Courses.GetValue(a => a.CourseID == applicationVW.CourseID, "CourseMakersJSON");

                List<int> CourseTypeMakerIDs = new();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CourseMakersJSON))
                {
                    CourseTypeMakerIDs = CourseMakersJSON.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
                }

                model = new()
                {
                    //process
                };
            }

            var htmlContent = await RenderViewToStringAsync(HttpContext, "Views/Application/P_Certificate.cshtml", model);
            var pdfData = await _pdfService.GeneratePDF2(htmlContent);
            var fileName = $"{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.pdf";
            Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"inline; filename={fileName}");
            return File(pdfData, "application/pdf");


        }


        private async Task<string> RenderViewToStringAsync<TModel>(HttpContext httpContext, string viewName, TModel model)
        {
            var routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values["controller"] = "Application";
            var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, routeData, new ActionDescriptor());

            var viewResult = _viewEngine.GetView(executingFilePath: null, viewPath: viewName, isMainPage: true);
            if (!viewResult.Success)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Sayfa bulunamadı: {viewName}");
            }

            var viewDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary())
            {
                Model = model
            };

            using var sw = new StringWriter();
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                actionContext,
                viewResult.View,
                viewDictionary,
                new TempDataDictionary(actionContext.HttpContext, _tempDataProvider),
                sw,
                new HtmlHelperOptions());

            await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);

            return sw.ToString();
        }
```

When I want to get a picture, the code on my view page is as follows

```
<img src="~/Images/Image/logo-1.png" alt="Logo" style="height:70px" srcset="" />
```

The code of the places where the text-center should be is on the view page like this;

```
<div class="col col-12 text-center" >
```

what can i do about it? My view page and pdf view do not match, can you help with this?

Comment: Where are the mismatches between the two? Can't display the picture? According to this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf/issues/15), you need to provide the full path to display it in the PDF. The rest of the content doesn't make any difference except that the CSS styles are lost. dinktopdf does not seem to support modern CSS.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I agree to you, dinktopdf is not supported modern css. I had to give a border between the style tags for the table. For image files, I realized that it is not visible because I work locally.

Comment: So you just have a mismatch caused by missing CSS styles?

Comment: for example; <div class="col col-12 text-center"> is not working but its work like this  <div class="col col-12 text-center" style="text-align:center;">

Comment: This is normal as it does not support modern CSS. You may need to specify the element's style directly instead of using class etc.